# Can Someone Decode Sha1 (user +password+salt)

Tags: mysql, sha1

```
const admin_user = 'nimda';
const admin_pass = 'df4044de3cf4f69e87974bc740f6a9b80554f51e'; // sha1(user + password + salt)
const admin_salt = 'avwbeebk';
```

Answer (score 1):

SHA1 is a one-way hash: it cannot be "decoded".

Comment: That is sad to know can i know how can i make my own sha1 with user + password + salt thanks Dev

Comment: Do you mean you have a script and want to know how to use it? Maybe convert the source code to a modern one-way hash?

Comment: Thanks I have only 2 files which im having trouble with its running Ferpect but i cant login to admin panel :(